# How to create an update query to extract xml values stored as text into new columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have an existing table that stores XML in a text column, as this format is no longer required I have created columns for each attribute.

The XML is as follows, just a single node:

```
<TimeLapse QueryID="308" IntervalType="1" GroupType="C" Accumulate="Y" FrameRate="2" StartDateTime="2009-05-20T00:00:00.0000000" />
```

Here are the new columns:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TimeLapse] 
ADD
    [QueryID] [int] null,
    [IntervalType] [varchar] (10) null,
    [GroupingType] [varchar](10) null,
    [Accumulate] [bit] default 'FALSE',
    [FrameRate] [int] null,
    [PeriodFixedStartDate] [datetime] NULL
```

What is the update query I need to perform to extract the XML into the new columns?

Comment: Use XQUERY. What have you tried so far? Why didn't it work?

Comment: P.s. considering that the value of the node `StartDateTime` is accurate to 1/1000000 of a second, I would use a `datetime2(7)` for your column as otherwise you'll lose a significant volume of accuracry (`datetime` is only accurate to 1/300 of a second). Unless the reason it has `00:00:00.0000000` is because they are all have that value; then you'd be better of with `date`.

Comment: Sorry my laptop battery just died, I'm on phone now. I started by casting the XML text to XML then use nodes method to get to a particular attribute, it was a shot in the dark that didn't work

Comment: Accuracy on time only needs to be to the minute, whoever's previously designed the data was quite ambitious:)

Comment: If only to a minute, then `smalldatetime`, seems like a better choice. :)

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned into the comments, you simply need to use XQUERY to extract the values:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TimeLapse (NotXMLColumn varchar(MAX));
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.TimeLapse (NotXMLColumn)
VALUES('<TimeLapse QueryID="308" IntervalType="1" GroupType="C" Accumulate="Y" FrameRate="2" StartDateTime="2009-05-20T00:00:00.0000000" />')
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TimeLapse] 
ADD
    [QueryID] [int] null,
    [IntervalType] [varchar] (10) null,
    [GroupingType] [varchar](10) null,
    [Accumulate] [bit] default 'FALSE',
    [FrameRate] [int] null,
    [PeriodFixedStartDate] [smalldatetime] NULL;
GO

UPDATE TL
SET QueryID = XMLColumn.value('(TimeLapse/@QueryID)[1]','int'),
    [IntervalType] = XMLColumn.value('(TimeLapse/@IntervalType)[1]','varchar(10)'),
    [GroupingType] = XMLColumn.value('(TimeLapse/@GroupType)[1]','varchar(10)'),
    [Accumulate] = CASE XMLColumn.value('(TimeLapse/@Accumulate)[1]','char(1)') WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    [FrameRate] = XMLColumn.value('(TimeLapse/@FrameRate)[1]','int'),
    [PeriodFixedStartDate] = XMLColumn.value('(TimeLapse/@StartDateTime)[1]','smalldatetime')
FROM dbo.TimeLapse TL
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CONVERT(xml,NotXMLColumn)))V(XMLColumn);

GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.TimeLapse;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e5cac8195a51a3a6b783fd833461bdc2)

Comment: Ok, but does that change a bit when XMLColumn is a varchar

Comment: You can use `VALUES` to convert the value in the `FROM`, @Hank. You should really be storing XML as `xml` though; that's what the data type is therefore, after all.

Comment: Lol, it wasn't created by me, someone 10yrs ago did, thanks for your help though, I will test this out in the morning